# Is it possible to use the generic type to determine runtime functionality?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a situation where I might have some code like this:

```js
const data = fetchSomeData(); //Can be anything 
const checkedData = checkDataIs<SomeSpecificType>(data); 

// now I can treat checkedData as SomeSpecificType
```

That is, at compile time I know what shape the data should be, and want to write my code as such, have all the advantages of type checking, but at runtime I need to run a function first to check that. (And it'll throw an error if the data doesn't match).

I know that I can achieve this functionality by writing individual functions for each type I want to check, eg:

```js
type Foo = {
    id: number; 
}

type Bar = {
    name: string; 
}

function checkFoo(data: any) : Foo {
      try {
          if (typeof data.id === 'number'){
              return data as Foo; 
          }
          else {
              throw new Error(); 
          }
      }catch (e) {
          throw new ("Failed validation")
      }
}

function checkBar(data : any) : Bar {
      try {
          if (typeof data.name === 'string'){
              return data as Bar; 
          }
          else {
              throw new Error(); 
          }
      }catch (e) {
          throw new ("Failed validation")
      }
}
```

This would work fine.

The question is - could I create a function that takes a generic param T, to determine which functionality is run at runtime?

eg something like:

```
function checkItem<T extends Foo|Bar>(data:any) : T {

    // if T is Foo
    return checkFoo(data); 

    //If T is Bar
    return checkBar(data); 

}
```

I think technically this should be possible in the sense that we're not asking for runtime type awareness - what this would be doing is compiling different code depending on what the generic parameter is.

Comment: You can't do anything at run time based on types. Generic or otherwise.

Comment: Given that the type system is part of TypeScript and not JavaScript, what do you perceive to be the difference between "runtime type awareness" and "compiling different code depending on the type of the generic parameter"?  In any case, it can't be done this way.  See [TypeScript Design Non-Goal #5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals).

Comment: @jcalz Alright cool, that's the canonical kind of answer I'm looking for you can post that as an answer.

Comment: But to answer your question - say you had `type Foo = {name: string}` and `type Bar = {name: string};` distingushing between these at runtime is what I would call 'runtime type awareness'. Whereas what I'm asking for is creating different compiled code at _compile time_ , based on the two type declarations.

Comment: TypeScript needs to be transpiled to JavaScript.  Either `type Foo = {name: string}` and `type Bar = {name: string}` gets *erased* from the emitted JavaScript, in which case you obviously can't tell them apart... or they get *compiled into different things* like `const FooType = {name: "string"}` and `const BarType = {id: "number"}` in which case you *can* tell them apart.  I can't envision a way to have "runtime type awareness" without "compiling different type stuff to different JavaScript".  Unless you're thinking of some sort of TypeScript runtime that isn't JavaScript?

Comment: @dwjohnston `type Foo = {name: string}` and `type Bar = {name: string}` are actually the same type. That is, at compile time, they are indistinguishable from the type system's perspective because it is a structural type system. There are two axies here, structural versus nominal and erased versus reified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical answer to this question is a blunt "you can't do this".  It's a [non-goal of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) to

> add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type system. Instead, encourage programming patterns that do not require run-time metadata.

---

The answer *could* just stop there, but it might be helpful to see how to get *similar* behavior to this without requiring TypeScript to emit different code for different types.  In this case, I'd write some [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) functions which return `boolean` values based on whether or not the input argument is of the guarded type.  Say like this:

```
namespace Type {
    export function Foo(x: any): x is Foo {
        return x && "id" in x && typeof x.id === "number";
    }
    export function Bar(x: any): x is Bar {
        return x && "name" in x && typeof x.name === "string";
    }
}
```

Here, `Type.Foo` and `Type.Bar` are similar to the logic in your `checkFoo()` and `checkBar()` functions. And note that `Type.Foo` and `Type.Bar` are functions that do exist at runtime, although we have imbued them in the type system with the property that they can be used to narrow an `any` value to a `Foo` or a `Bar`.

Then we can write your `checkItem()` function like this:

```
function checkItem<T>(guard: (x: any) => x is T, data: any): T {
    if (!guard(data)) {
        throw "Failed validation";
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

You can think of `checkItem` as not taking a *type parameter* (although it is generic) which will be gone at runtime, but as taking a *type guard function* which will exist.

If you have something which might or might not be a `Foo`

```
const maybeFoo = JSON.parse(Math.random() < 0.5 ? '{"id": 123}' : '{"di": 321}');
```

Then you can call `checkItem()` like this:

```
const foo: Foo = checkItem(Type.Foo, maybeFoo); // could be Failed validation here
console.log(foo.id.toFixed(1)); // 123.0 if it reaches here
```

We've changed from `checkItem<Foo>(maybeFoo)` to `checkItem(Type.Foo, maybeFoo)`, which, if you squint at it enough, is sort of the same thing.  We are specifying `Foo` both ways, but the latter way is doing so with a thing that exists at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCWATALigDsBXAWwCMIAnAbnQF911RIoAhAQxuTSkzZiXchCIBnYDRzEA5g2bpho8WC4BjaABVw0DNigQAHmDg1gUAGali64DjjFYCABRGiXYiACURI7nFnRH0DbBoIYFIaJ38AMlioACJ8RNwYqHioNgg4SygjADp8ZCQURLIqWkSGA2YDY1NzKxs7ByduGjcPL198gM4eNEFQqHDI6L7M8pEIVJlJhOzc-ILlaFKyyWk5auGoZkVrW3tHKHUACwh1AGsASWAIcgAeLQA+F1lSHkIoLqhPHzIV59HCBLQAGigeC4wC43R8RC0QwMODyLgAhJ9vi5obDvN5kSMsucaHAAO5JGBcHAAGwgeCgADcuDT8DC2rtaoYaeI9HsDGMok5cVwatgDix1I5JFByFwQNR4IgUAApADKAHkAHIFNQ0XkuACyMPOBRonjwcHILgJTygAAYCgBWKAAfigAHJUMk8IkiABGABMAGZGB6oEQvYk8Dg-VBg4H-WHvAx0FLiDLLAgiEq+BcrncHtadJACkrIXKFRAlSmoAB6OtnOCkGkM6iwal0hnM1m4tpQS7hSXSuB0go0uCyFxZuBFPAFYBwGA4Iz0lz+-F0euNoPBgr2lhAA)